# Ranking/counting in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data with binary values in one column that look like:

[image]

The code I used to make this is as follows:

```
 Binary_Num = pd.DataFrame({'Bin_ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                     'Bin_Num' : [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]})
 Binary_Num.set_index('Bin_ID', inplace=True)
```

Is there any way that I can create a new column that would look like as below:

[image]

It is a kind of ranking, I think. I don't know the technical word that I can use to ask this question!!

Comment: `df.groupby('Bin_Num').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: @user3483203  , Brilliant. Thanks for your quick reply. It worked.